Help with integral $\int_b^\infty dxe^{-x}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-a^2}{x^2-b^2}}$
I'm trying to evaluate the integral
$$ \int_b^\infty dxe^{-x}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-a^2}{x^2-b^2}}, $$
where $b>a>0$. This looks like it should be doable, but I've thrown every technique I can think of at it, and nothing's come out of it. Mathematica has also been of limited help. If any of you can lend a hand, I'd really appreciate it!
Things I've tried:
Common integral techniques like substitution, integration by parts, etc. I haven't found any that made this integral any nicer.
Laplace transforms. If you substitute $u=x-b$, then this becomes a Laplace transform of $\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2bx+b^2-a^2}{x^2+2bx}}$. But none of the properties of the Laplace transform are useful for what I'm trying to do, as far as I can tell, so I don't think this actually helps me.
Contour integration. The trouble with this is that, because the exponential is real, the large circular part of the contour has to be entirely within the right half-plane in order for it to vanish. The most natural choice then is for the contour to be a quarter-circle to the right of $z=b$ (with a smaller arc around $z=b$ to avoid crossing the pole there), with one side of the quarter circle placed along the real axis and the other side parallel to the imaginary axis. The integral that emerges from the latter of these segments is even messier than the one I'm trying to solve, so this doesn't appear to be a fruitful direction.
Finding some special function. If you substitute $x=b\cosh u$, then this almost matches the integral formula for the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $K_\alpha$ (specifically, if $a=0$, then the integral would become $bK_1(b)$). There are far more special functions like that than I'm familiar with, so maybe it's just a matter of performing the right substitution and being familiar with the right function?
Feynman's trick. This is the one that brought me closest to a solution. I defined
$$ f(s)=\int_b^\infty dxe^{-x}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-a^2}{x^2-sa^2}}. $$
$f(1)=e^{-b}$, and we want to find $f\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)$. I was able to show that the derivatives at $s=1$ are
$$ f^{(n)}(1)=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}\frac{a^{2n}}{2^{2n-1}}\int_b^\infty\frac{dxe^{-x}}{\left(x^2-a^2\right)^n}. $$
In principle, these integrals can be solved using partial fractions, and then we can perform a Taylor expansion about $s=1$ in order to get a series representation of $f\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)$. The problem is that, while I can evaluate $f^{(n)}(1)$ for any specific value of $n$, I wasn't able to get an expression for $f^{(n)}(1)$ in terms of arbitrary $n$ that I could plug into a Taylor series.
Edit
Okay, I think I figured it out! You can use the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{\left(x^2-a^2\right)^n}$ about $x=\infty$,
$$ \frac{1}{\left(x^2-a^2\right)^n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(n+i-1)!}{(n-1)!i!}\frac{a^{2i}}{x^{2n+2i}} $$
to get a series expression for $f^{(n)}(1)$. Note that we're using the series about $x=\infty$, rather than $x=0$, because there's a discontinuity at $x=\pm a$, and our integral takes place when $x>a$. So you have to do your power series about some point greater than $a$, and $\infty$ seems like the most natural choice. So we get
$$ f^{(n)}(1)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(n+i-1)!}{(n-1)!i!}a^{2n+2i}\Gamma(1-2n-2i,b), $$
where $(\ldots)_n$ indicates the rising Pochhammer symbol, and $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. Plugging this into a Taylor series for $f(s)$ about $s=1$, we get
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n\frac{(n+i-1)!}{n!(n-1)!i!}a^{2n+2i}\Gamma(1-2n-2i,b)\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right)^n \\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(n-1)!(m-n)!}a^{2m}\Gamma(1-2m,b)\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right)^n \\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\delta_{m0}e^{-b}+\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n+1}\binom{m-1}{n}\frac{a^{2m}}{(n+1)!}\Gamma(1-2m,b)\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1\right)^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
where in the second line we defined $m=n+i$, and in the third line we took out the $n=0$ term and then redefined $n\to n+1$. With a bit more manipulation, it's easy to show that the inner sum is a hypergeometric function, so we get
$$ \int_b^\infty dxe^{-x}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-a^2}{x^2-b^2}}=e^{-b}+\frac{1}{2}\left(b^2-a^2\right)\sum_{m=0}^\infty a^{2m}\Gamma(-1-2m,b){}_2F_1\left(-m,\frac{3}{2};2;1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right). $$
I ran some numerical checks in Mathematica, which seemed to confirm this result. This obviously isn't the prettiest result; I doubt there's any way to simplify it further, but, if anyone is aware of some useful identity involving the hypergeometric function and the incomplete gamma function, please let me know!

The pattern is far away to be clear

I'm sorry, I don't understand — what pattern are you talking about? And what do you mean by it being far away?

I agree with you ! For a given $n$,  $f^{(n)}(1)$ (even if ugly) can be computed but not for general $n$. I tried tools for pattern recognition with no result. Cheers :-)

Got it — thanks anyway for looking into it! Also, not sure if you get notified when I edit my post, so if not I wanted to let you know that I've found a solution, in case you're interested.

Yes I am ! Congratulations !
